# Storing the wrong image filepath in Sqlite database. Objective C, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a sqlite database in which I can store images and data and then display it in a `ViewController` to edit.

I don't have a problem with storing the path in my database.

I am having some trouble where when I finish using the camera or photo roll I use the following code with `UIImagePickerController`. The UIPickerController class saves the image to the directory and the save class saves the image path but renames it.

But the big trouble comes in where I use a similar piece of code to send to my file where
I save my stuff in my database.

What this code does because it is only executed after I push save , is it renames the filepath from when I first ended the `UIImagePickerController` this means I am storing the wrong image path to the database and it shows in the previous entry.

So after I use my camera or photo roll I get the following in my NSLOG:

This is for when I use `UIImagePickerController` (Which is the path I want to put in my database)

```
2013-06-06 17:50:48.019 shotplacementguide001[7235:907] photo_1.png - - /var/mobile/Applications/EE759F67-DA8F-4232-BE4F-35D16D047D24/Documents/photo_1.png
```

And this is for when I push save:

```
2013-06-06 17:50:53.827 shotplacementguide001[7235:907] photo_2.png - - /var/mobile/Applications/EE759F67-DA8F-4232-BE4F-35D16D047D24/Documents/photo_2.png
```

This is my code for the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo_%i.png", [dirContents count]];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
// self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:fileName];
self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName];
NSLog(@"%@ - - %@", self.presentImageFileName,imagePath );


// Then save the image to the Documents directory
NSString *mediaType1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType1 isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}

NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    animalEditImageView.image = image;
    if (_newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,
                                       @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
}
```

And for when I push save:

```
-(IBAction) done:(id) sender
{
Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];
    customer.dateTimeZone = self.dateTimeTextField.text;
    customer.species = self.speciesTextField.text;
    customer.gender = self.genderTextField.text;
    customer.location_name = self.locationTextField.text;
    customer.latitude = self.speciesTextField.text;
    customer.longitude = self.speciesTextField.text;
    customer.firearm = self.firearmTextField.text;
    customer.comments = self.commentsTextField.text;

    // Capture the file name of the image
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = addCustomerFileName;
    self.customerToEdit.imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    // self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:fileName];
    self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@ - - %@", self.presentImageFileName,self.customerToEdit.imagePath );
}
```

How can I change my above code to only take the imagepath that I saved in `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker` not to rename it without actually saving the renamed image to the to the directory like I have done it which is wrong.

Because I save the wrong image path so it will display in the previous entry `EditViewController`.

I am having trouble using customer.imagePath in the `UIPickerController` class that I have and using info in my save class because of this:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally coded a solution that just took the filepath from the UIPhotoPickerController and stored it instead of renaming it.

```
 // Capture the file name of the image
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = addCustomerFileName;
    self.customerToEdit.imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    // self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:fileName];
    self.presentImageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@ - - %@", self.presentImageFileName,self.customerToEdit.imagePath );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  problem is caused by the "naming" algorithm, there is no rename there. So first, you get the files count in the documents folder which by your logs seems to be `1` for the first call, you name the image `image_1.jpg` and you save it into the `documents` directory after that you simply have `2` files in your `documents` folder so when you try again to get the image file path your files count from documents folder will be `2` so you get the `image_2.jpg` file name.

So we identified the issue, now let's fix it. What you should do is save the file path if you can, and send it to the view controller that will add it to the database or you could just simply change the naming algorithm, you could use the current date ([NSDate date]) as the file name and you sort them and get the last image added...or other algorithm.

Comment: I already can do that, My question was essentially how do I change this statement in my save class to reflect the path that I already got in my picker?     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo_%i.png", [dirContents count]];

Comment: But not with the NSdate that you mentioned though.

Comment: It's like I made a fake path with the statement in my comment above. because photo_2.png doesn't actually exist in the directory.